Hypergeometric functions in Wireless communication: Seeking guidance for Performance analysis
I am transitioning from pure mathematics to wireless communications and am particularly intrigued by the mathematical challenges in analyzing Nakagami-m fading channels. These channels are widely used to model wireless environments, and performance metrics such as outage probability and ergodic capacity often involve advanced tools like hypergeometric functions, Meijer G-functions, and asymptotic analysis.
I have been reading about how these tools are applied but still struggle to identify the deeper mathematical structure behind them.
My central question is:
What are the key mathematical approaches or open problems in analyzing performance metrics (e.g., outage probability, capacity) for Nakagami-m fading channels, especially in RIS-aided or multi-antenna systems?
While I am aware of some standard results, I am eager to understand if there are any unexplored challenges or innovative mathematical methods in this area.
I need your help. Thanks a real lot!

Hi! Welcome here! This might really be a question that the folks over at https://signals.stackexchange.com are better at answering :)

@MarcusMüller Copy that, sir.
